# VS Code Not Highlighting Errors/Missing Imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier-vscode

VS Code stopped highlighting errors/missing imports. Using Prettier, ESLint extensions, but no luck.
I tried to reinstall again, didn't work still. Any suggestions?

More:
Version: 1.84.2 (user setup)
Commit: 1a5daa3a0231a0fbba4f14db7ec463cf99d7768e
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If Visual Studio Code has stopped highlighting errors or missing imports, there are several troubleshooting steps you can take to resolve the issue. Here are some suggestions:

**1**. Check ESLint Configuration:
Make sure your ESLint configuration is correct. Check your .eslintrc file for any errors or misconfigurations. You can use the ESLint extension in VS Code to see if there are any configuration errors reported.

**2**. Check Prettier Configuration:
Similar to ESLint, ensure your Prettier configuration is correct. Check your .prettierrc file for any issues. The Prettier extension in VS Code can also provide information about configuration errors.

**3**. Check VS Code Settings:
Verify your VS Code settings related to ESLint and Prettier. Open your settings (Ctrl + ,) and search for settings related to ESLint and Prettier. Ensure that the extensions are enabled and configured correctly.

**4**. Check File Associations:
Ensure that the files you are working with have the correct file associations. For example, JavaScript files should have the .js extension. Sometimes, VS Code may not recognize files correctly if they have an uncommon extension.

Comment: Thanks. I checked all of them. No luck